# Handle socket.io users sockets with cluster?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I would like to know what is the best practice of handling my case:

I want to have private channel for each user, which will be able to access it from multiple clients (browser tabs / 2 different computers in parallel for ex.) and authorize them (since it's private channel I want to make sure that only the authorized user will be able to get the notifications).

All of those, will has to be handled with scalable app.

Thanks